# PHP Arrow operator - how do I assign a variable

Tags: php, operators

I'm trying to pass a variable into an operator instead of having it be fixed

```
$client ->setDeveloperKey('a very long hexadecimal string');
```

This is how the script is written to work and it works - some value is a very long hex code...

The script I'm writing takes the developer key from an input i.e.  `$value='some value'` is already defined BEFORE the statement.

Instead of being fixed, I'd like to assign `$value` into the `setDeveloperKey` operator - its coming in as a function i.e.

```
callGoogle ($query,$devkey)
```

where `callGoogle` is the function.  However when I try

```
$client ->setDeveloperKey($devkey);
```

the script doesn't work...in other words its the wrong syntax to assign my developer key (string) to the operator.

Nor does

```
$client ->setDeveloperKey = $devkey;
```

What is the correct PHP syntax to assign the `$value` variable to the `$client - > setDeveloperKey` operator?

Comment: What is your `$value` var? Did you assign like: `$value = "some value";` before.

Comment: Where's the code for the class (or at least for the `setDeveloperKey()` method), and how are you testing if `setDeveloperKey()` has worked or not

Comment: its Google API code - a maze.... all I'm trying to do is pass $value = "some value" before and have the syntax match up so it performs correctly

Comment: assuming that `$value` is set correctly, `$client->setDeveloperKey($value);` should work fine. Is `$value` being set in the same scope? (ie confirm that you're not setting it in another function and expecting it to work all through)

Comment: $client->setDeveloperKey($devkey); doesn't work - the script gives an error. - i'm perplexed. thats why I wrote this post...lol

Comment: If it gives an error, then TELL US WHAT ERROR IT GIVES

Answer (score 0):

First check the type of your $value and also check if that class method accept that value type. From what I can see its a Google_Client API and that method accepts **Strings**

Comment: $value is a string - i put the developer code in a variable - it is read from a function...

callGoogle ($query,$devkey) where Devkey is my API developer key.

Answer (score 0):

Well what type of object is `$client`? You have to define your own class, and create a function called `setDeveloperKey`, or this is a pre existing class / function, the syntax would be `$client->setDeveloperKey('foo')`;

The original class should look something like this:

```
class Client {
    protected $DeveloperKey;

    public function setDeveloperKey($Key) {
        $this->DeveloperKey = $Key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this works:

```
$obj->method('test');
```

Then this works too:

```
$value = 'test';
$obj->method($value);
```

You must be messing somewhere else.